# Create round UIButton with custom drawRect: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

My goal is to create a custom `UIButton` subclass, that creates a round (or round rect) button with some additional features.

After some searching, I found that simply setting the `cornerRadius` of the button layer is the easiest way to make the button round:

@implementation MyRoundButton

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
        [self setupView];

    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
        [self setupView];

    return self;
}

-(void)setupView {    
    self.layer.cornerRadius = MIN(self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width) / 2.0;
}
```

This works fine to, as long as I do not override `drawRect:`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

Of course I would like to add some custom drawing code to `drawRect:` but even if only `[super drawRect:rect]` the button is not round anymore: It drawn as rectangle within its bounds.

**How is this possible?** How can overriding a method with a simple super call change the behavior at all?

**How can I avoid this problem?** I already tried to let the layer unchanged and to simply draw the background manually in `drawRect:`. However the button draws its background rect anyway and my custom drawing is on top of it.

So, how to solve this?

Comment: "How can overriding a method with a simple super call change the behavior " UIButton could be checking for an override and behaving differently. It doesn't need to implement itself with drawRect at all.

Comment: This might be an explanation, but what could be the reason for such an implementation? Code that changes nothing changes something? Quite strange... However: The actual question is something else: How to create a round button that uses `drawRect:`

Comment: Why do you want to call `[super drawRect:rect];` ?

Comment: You might have to set `opaque` to false on your button.

Comment: The `super` call should show, that even nothing changes, something changed. The reason for this was described/answerd by @jlehr. Changing the `opaque` value of the button does not have any influence on wether the layer draws its background or not.

Answer (score 2):

The layer in your example conceptually contains a background with a corner radius, but the empty override of `drawRect:` causes that to be ignored. That's because, ordinarily, an instance of `UIView` depends on its built-in layer (an instance of `CALayer`) to render its content, so `drawRect:` isn't called. However, the layer is capable of delegating drawing behavior to its view, and will do so if you implement `drawRect:`.

If you're simply subclassing `UIView`, this shouldn't present any problem. However, subclassing a framework component such as `UIButton` is a bit dicier. One potential issue is the call to `-[super drawRect:]`; it's hard to know precisely what mischief that might cause, but that may be the source of the problem. By default, a `UIButton` doesn't need to do any custom drawing; it contains a nested instance of a private class, `UIButtonLabel`, that draws the button's title.

Instead of trying to override the drawing behavior of a class whose inner details are private, consider using one or more static images and simply setting the button's background image property for one or more states.

Comment: Thank you very much, that sound pretty reasonable. However I am not sure it this completely true: I would understand if implementing `drawRect:` would be uses as trigger to switch from layer-drawing to view-drawing and thus the layer would simply be ignored. But this is not the case. If `drawRect:` is implemented, the layer will always its background and I found no way to prevent it from doing so. So layer-drawing is still active and I can only add view-drawing, but my goal is to **replace** the layer drawing. How can I do this?

Comment: I edited my answer. Have you tried eliminating the call to `-[super drawRect:]`?

Comment: The `super` call was only used to demonstrate, that even a override version of `drawRect:` which does not change anything leads to the Problem. Removing the `supper` call does not change anything.

I now understand, that even adding a override version is enough to  change something. However Ithe main goal is the same: How to override UIButton, make it round and use custom drawing at the same time? Custom drawing only does not work, since the I cannot prevent the button from dawing its background layer. Setting the layer `cornerRadius` does not work, since I cannot use custom drawing any more

Answer (score 0):

See if this changes anything...

```
-(void)setupView {    
    self.layer.cornerRadius = MIN(self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width) / 2.0;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: This partially solves the problem: The button is now round, even if I use custom drawing (override `drawRect:`), but now the buttons clipped to its bounds (surprise, surprise :) and thus a **shadow**, that is added to the layer is not visible anymore...

Comment: Sorry, didn't see anything in your question about needing a shadow. There's more than one way to do things... maybe if you post what you're end-goal is?